# How to indent a block of text rightward by 2 whitespace characters in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-binding, indentation

How to indent a block of text rightward by 2 whitespace characters in Emacs?

How to indent a block of text rightward by 4 whitespace characters in Emacs?

[EDIT] I need a method that doesn't interfere with CUA mode.

Answer (score 4):

Try the key binding <kbd>C-x TAB</kbd> (aka <kbd>C-x C-i</kbd>) which is bound to [`indent-rigidly`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html), which indents a region by a single space.

So, you'd indent by two by pressing that twice setting the region around the code you want to indent and typing:

```
C-x C-i C-x C-i
```

Or, you can pass a numeric prefix with

```
C-u 2 C-x C-i
```

To get 4 spaces, do a prefix with 4

```
C-u 4 C-x C-i
```

And, as a bonus, you can remove spaces with a negative prefix argument.  Removing 4 spaces is accomplished by

```
C-u - 4 C-x C-i
```

Comment: How to set the starting and ending points of the block to which I want to indent?

Comment: @user6076: the same way you mark a region for any other purpose. In one of the positions, press `C-space`, and navigate to the other.

Comment: There are two ways to mark a region of code: `M-x mark-sexp` and `M-x mark-defun`.

Comment: @choroba Doing what you described deletes the text in the block.

Comment: @Trey Jackson What are shortcuts (keybindings) for `M-x mark-sexp` and `M-x mark-defun`?

Comment: @Trey Jackson I found that `C-M-@` is the keybinding for `M-x mark-sexp`. I do that at the beginning of the block. Then what steps do I do to mark its end?

Comment: @duperuser When you're at the beginning of a block, `M-x mark-sexp` will put the mark at the *end* - which is all you need to do.

Comment: To select a block of text to indent: 1) move cursor to the beginning of the block by mouse or up arrow key; 2) `C`-`M`-`@` 3) move cursor to the end of the block 4) `C`-`X` `C`-`i`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use
[Rectangles](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Rectangles).

Mark the beginning of the region with <kbd>C-Space</kbd>, go to then
end of the region and then type
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>.

Example:

```
v----------------------- cursor position
blabla bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

<kbd>C-Space</kbd><kbd>C-n</kbd><kbd>C-n</kbd>

```
blabla bla bla bla
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
^----------------------- cursor position
```

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>M-2</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

```
  blabla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla
  bla bla bla
  ^----------------------- cursor position
```

Comment: By `go to then end of the region`, what concrete keyboard and/or mouse movement do you do?  If I use down arrow key to do that, the following `C-x` will delete the text.

Comment: As described in the example I've used `C-n`. `C-space` pushes a mark at the current position and `C-n` goes to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your edit "I need a method that doesn't interfere with CUA mode." Assuming you have CUA mode enabled, I would also like to recommend you to try C-Enter (cua-set-rectangle-mark). Here is the sequence that works for me.

1. Move the cursor to the start (top-left) of the block.
2. Press C-ENTER.
3. Move the cursor down to the end (bottom-left) of the block.
4. Press SPACE twice or four times depending on your indentation width.
5. Press C-ENTER to quit the selection.